# sqlserver to oracle datetime

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can we convert datetime from sql server to oracle?

for instance:

```
set @month=Convert(nvarchar(10),(select MONTH(Getdate())))
```

What should the code look like in Oracle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the month number, use this:

```
Select to_char(SYSDATE,'MM') FROM DUAL
```